# Orchard takes too long to load - How to set SysCache DefaultExpiration?

Tags: orchardcms, syscache

I have a simple Orchard website with about 100 blog posts. If no one enters the website for more than 5 minutes loading the page takes about 10-15 seconds. This happens only on the blog page where it has to load a bunch of posts. The rest of the pages load quickly (2-3 secs). I have the SysCache module and "warmup" enabled. Before I enabled SysCache it took 10-15secs to load the blog page every single time.

I couldn't find a way to override the SysCache DefaultExpiration property anywhere in the configuration files. I re-wrote the SysCache plugin (copied/pasted) and hardcoded the DefaultExpirtaion value (1day). It made no difference.

How can I solve this load time issue?

Thanks,

Eyal

Comment: It should be a lot faster than that without syscache. Profile it and find out what's slowing it down.

Comment: We're using an SDF and we kind of lost the password for it :). Do you have an idea how to retrieve it? I tried decrypting the password in the settings text file but I was kind of guessing and using all kinds of online decryption services. None worked.

Comment: never mind. password issue solved. We are now migrating it to a "real" DB (an azure one) and testing to see if the problem persists.